# AngularJS (ng-repeat directive) with Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I have a question regarding the directive ng-repeat. Is it possible to perform manipulation to each item in a collection?

```
 <div ng-repeat = "item in items">

 </div>
```

Is there any possible way to call a Meteor method to perform some sort of manipulation to each item?

I'll be more specific. What I'm doing is using the meteor twitter accounts and every time a user logs in, it stored in a database.

index.ng.html :

```
  <div ng-controller = "TweetsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat = "t in twitterAccs">
        <img src = "{{t.services.twitter.profile_image_url_https}}">
        <br>
        <i>@{{t.services.twitter.screenName}}</i>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
   </div>
```

JS file :

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  angular.module('twitter-example',['angular-meteor']);
  angular.module('twitter-example').controller('TweetsCtrl',   ['$scope','$meteor', function($scope,$meteor) {
$scope.twitterAccs = $meteor.collection(Meteor.users);
  }]);
}
```

Right now, its able to get the image and the twitter handle. What I want to do is extract the number of followers and friends but that requires OAUTH from Twitter. Since those require special keys from Twitter, I know I have to put that information in the if (Meteor.isServer) scope.

Comment: You can use filters to manipulate each item.

Comment: What kind of manipulation? Can you add more code?

Comment: Look at angular-meteror - http://angular-meteor.com/ . It allows binding between angular and the meteor server, so maybe that can help you.